# WPF resizing TextBlock

Tags: wpf, grid, resize, textblock

I have a textblock in a grid in WPF.

I want the text to dynamically size (font) when resized. At the moment textboxes, comboboxes do this, but the the textblock stays the same. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to manually rig a TextBlock to do this, just edit the default template of a TextBox and remove the border and background, then in the style make it set the IsReadOnly flag. This way you get the textblock sizing, as well as copy-paste for free.

Comment: Use Expression Blend "Edit Template", or if you've only got VS, it's at http://pastie.org/714760

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ViewBox for this.

eg:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

use expression blend for getting the default template of TextBox, then you can edit it as you required.